# How to fetch file names defined in Russian character set using Apache CMIS API

Tags: java, apache, cmis, filenet

I have a requirement to fetch files from FileNet Server using the Apache CMIS API.
I am able to fetch filenames defined in English, Spanish and French but I am unable to fetch the names of Russian language files.

Russian language filenames are being returned as `?????`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I have edited your question a little bit- to make it clearer and help people find it. 

The first line did not tell us anything different from the second line where the proper question began so I deleted it, same with the last.

To show the output from your request "`" around the "?" symbols.

You will need to show the code that is requesting the file names so that people can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTF-8 encoding. What do you use to working with CMIS? It is only two options, your server does not support UTF-8 or client-side don't understand UTF-8.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply,I tried encoding filename it is giving some encoded string how to get exact filename ?

Comment: can you show me source-code? It is possible to use non-CMIS client?

Comment: Hi it is not possible to use non-CMIS API as i moved from filenet java api to CMIS api here is the code snippet i am using to fetch filename from filenet using CMIS api

Comment: Code                                                                                                               Folder root = (Folder)session.getObjectByPath(rootFolderName);
ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = root.getChildren();
 for (CmisObject cmisObj : children) {
 if(cmisObj instanceof Document )
            {
             Document doc=(Document)cmisObj;
             doc.getName()
            }
 else if(cmisObj instanceof Folder )
            {
               Folder folderObj=(Folder)cmisObj;
             folderObj.getName()
            }
}

Answer (score 0):

Are the ‘???’ values being returned that way over-the-wire in the XML response (look at a trace to confirm) or is the OpenCMIS client translating them this way?  This is important to narrowing down whether this is an issue with the P8 server perhaps missing a Russian language pack (unlikely see **) or a mismatch with how the CMIS listener is encoding and the OpenCMIS client is decoding.

** Note I expect the language pack is there since otherwise you would have seen the response in en-US.

Comment: Thank you for reply  ,When i am trying to view documents from content navigator,filenet workplace XT Russian language is shown fine only the problems comes when i am trying to fetch using CMIS API.Even if i hit CMIS document download URL from browser it is returning Russian characters.Could you please tell me how to fix this issue :(